# Looking for variables which aren't assigned

Tags: php, smarty, isset

What could happen if my template looks for variables which weren't assigned?

For example:

```
var id = '{$tpl_id}';
```

This snippet is from my javascript code. I outputted the value and it is simply empty. I know I could use isset(). But I couldn't find anything about how Smarty handles non-existing variables. So, what happens if a template can't find a variable, because it wasn't assigned?

Answer (score 1):

If a variable isn't defined, it's treated as if it were an empty variable. No (non-logic) error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Hy
You have to use {`literal} {/literal}`
Example:

```
{literal}
<script>
var id = '{/literal}{$tpl_id}{literal}';
// keep coding
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: @Kel sorry forgot to write that you cannot work with variables which arent assignet.

Comment: sorry, aber das isch ned mini frag gsi :)